# Calf Muscle - Stiffness in calf muscle after running for long distance

Tags: running, long-distance-running

I ran for a long distance and developed stiffness in my calf muscles. I have tried stretching out and hydrating myself. Also I'm giving proper rest to my body. Now the stiffness is easing out a bit.

My question is, what regime or precautions should I follow so that I should not develop any more stiffness in my calf muscles? Would running again for short distance after 2-3 days will ease out the stiffness, as if I'm getting used to it?

And what normally is the recovery time?

Comment: Was this a one time thing that you ran the long distance? Or do you do it regularly? How much more than your regular was was the long distance?

Comment: Yes this was one time thing, but I'm gradually increasing my distance. I want to run for a half marathon in about 2 month time. I ran for 12.5 kms on Sunday and since then, the calf muscles have stiffened. When I walk, it appears like my calf muscles will tore away.

Comment: Some of the answers to your earlier question, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7452/3778, "how run a marathon in 12 weeks" has some recommendations on what to do when you are injured

Comment: @fredob - Thanks, I missed the connection. Guess all the predictions of "You're likely to be injured" were on the mark.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing, the people who have the best times for marathons don't measure as particularly flexible in the legs. It *could* be your body making appropriate adaptations.

Comment: Remember the golden rule of distance running: never increase the distance or speed with more than 5% per week.

Comment: @RobinAshe Thanks for motivation. I also feel the same thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you're necessarily injured per se, but that you've definitely overdone your training.

As stated in answers and comments to your other question, back off the distance, speed, or both for a bit. Your body needs time to adapt.

Comment: Yes I have rested for 4 days now. And the stiffness is almost gone. I took into consideration the views of other people and sticking to it.